# Entry inside audit log table for CUD operations on tables

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a DB e.g "dbAuditLogs" inside created tables like as mstUser,mstEmployee,mstDepartment and auditHistory. when any CUD operation performed on mstUser/mstEmployee/mstDepartment then want to register an entry inside auditHistory table. I can do this with the help of triggers but in future when number of tables increase or columns removed from existing table then we will need to make changes into TRIGGER as well. Also by creating multiple TRIGGERS db performance will become slow.
As per my understanding below are my queries

1. Is there any design pattern available like as "UnitOfWork" in
   MYSQL/NODEJS.
2. Is there any npm available which can handle Audit log
       from API.
3. Only trigger is the best option suited for above
       condition?

Trigger created by me

```
BEGIN
SET @json = "{";
SET @first = true;
IF (OLD.firstName!=NEW.firstName) THEN
  SET @first = false;
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "\"firstName\"", ":", "\"", NEW.firstName, "\"");
END IF;
IF (OLD.lastName!=NEW.lastName) THEN
  IF (!@first) THEN
    SET @json = CONCAT(@json, ",");
  END IF;
SET @first = false;
SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "\"lastName\"", ":", "\"", NEW.lastName, "\"");
END IF;
SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "}");
INSERT INTO mstAuditHistory (tableName,jsonData,recordId,userId,eventType) 
    VALUES ('contactDetails',@json, NEW.id, NEW.userId,'Update');    
END
```

Comment: *in future when number of tables increase or columns removed from existing table then we will need to make changes into TRIGGER as well.* And what's a problem? each data structure change will include trigger change appropriate to it. It's normally. Of course, you can make "universal" trigger which will obtain the info about current table structure, check each field for a change and log if... but performance will extremely degrade, because each record change will fire all of trigger's actions (get structure, compare each field...)...

Comment: *Only trigger is the best option suited for above condition?* I think the best option is to go from single queries to stored procedures which realize all logic you need - including logging.

Comment: @Akina How can i make universal trigger? For insert i get NEW.columnName, for Update i get NEW.columnName and OLD.columnName. you have any example then please share with me

Comment: *How can i make universal trigger?* It is universal in terms of table's structure change - no change needs trigger modifying. *For insert i get NEW.columnName, for Update i get NEW.columnName and OLD.columnName.* It's two different triggers - what's a problem? AFTER INSERT trigger logs NEW.columnName only, AFTER UPDATE trigger logs both NEW.columnName and OLD.columnName...

Comment: @Akina Above comment i added on trigger created by me. Which works perfect for contactDetails table but the problem is for multiple table i can't copy paste the same trigger. As every table have it's different table structure. that's reason I ask how can i make it generalize so I can use it on other table as well

Comment: @Akina As suggested i have updated the question

Comment: Why you store and handle JSON as string? Why you do not use [JSON data type and built-in functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)? *I ask how can i make it generalize so I can use it on other table* Do as described above. Ask `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for table structure, field names and types. Build query text as a string on a basis of table structure and execute it as `prepared statement` in a trigger. Or use this method from SP to create trigger text for each table and each action.

Comment: You will be in deep weeds if some string column contains a quote or backslash.  Rethink your idea of 'building' JSON.

Comment: @RickJames agreed so decided to perform log operation from API side.